# adb from Android Studio and terminal are not usable simultanously

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, terminal, adb

I'm using Linux Mint and I have an annoying problem with my adb:

I can use adb either from Android Studio (Android Monitor) or in terminal, but not both at the same time. Even the Android Studio Terminal found no devices if Android Monitor in Android Studio was running.

The workaround is to exit Android Studio and type 'adb kill-server' in terminal. After that I can use adb in terminal, and when I'm ready with my custom commands I have to restart Android Studio.

I have activated Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB Integration.

Any ideas to use adb through terminal even when Android Studio is running?

Comment: There can be only once instance of the adb per connected device. Either an Android Monitor OR a terminal. 
To avoid a restart you could try to select `-> File -> Invalidate caches`. Does the problem persist then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure that you are using single instance of `adb`.**

You are, most probably, using two instances of `adb`. With a single instance of `adb`, I can use it from external terminal, Android Studio terminal, and build/run projects from Android Studio simultaneously without restarting anything.

To verify if you are using single instance of `adb` run

```
$ which adb
```

or

```
$ type adb
```

from external terminal and one from Android Studio, and make sure they both are pointing to the same `adb`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I had a version of adb in /usr/bin and in another folder.